# Number of characters in a shell command's output

Tags: shell, string, variable

I am writing a script which needs to calculate the number of characters in a command's output in **a single step**.

For example, using the command `readlink -f /etc/fstab` should return `10` because the output of that command is 10 characters long.

This is already possible with stored variables using the following code:

```
variable="somestring";
echo ${#variable};
# 10
```

Unfortunately, using the same formula with a command-generated string does not work:

```
${#(readlink -f /etc/fstab)};
# bash: ${#(readlink -f /etc/fstab)}: bad substitution
```

I understand it is possible to do this by first saving the output to a variable:

```
variable=$(readlink -f /etc/fstab);
echo ${#variable};
```

But I would like to remove the extra step.

Is this possible? Compatibility with the Almquist shell (sh) using only in-built or standard utilities is preferable.

Comment: The output of `readlink -f /etc/fstab` is *11* characters. Don't forget the newline. Otherwise you'd see `/etc/fstabluser@cern:~$ ` when you ran it from a shell.

Comment: @PhilFrost you seem to have a funny prompt, do you work in CERN?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With [GNU expr](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expr):

```
$ expr length + "$(readlink -f /etc/fstab)"
10
```

The `+` there is a special feature of GNU `expr` to make sure the next argument is treated as a string even if it happens to be an `expr` operator like `match`, `length`, `+`...

The above will strip any trailing newline of output. To work around it:

```
$ expr length + "$(readlink -f /etc/fstab; printf .)" - 2
10
```

The result was subtracted to *2* because the final newline of `readlink` and the character `.` we added.

With Unicode string, `expr` does not seem to work, because it returns length of string in bytes instead of characters count (See [line 654](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/coreutils/src/expr.c))

```
$ LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 expr length ăaa
4
```

So, you can use:

```
$ printf "ăaa" | LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 wc -m
3
```

---

POSIXLY:

```
$ expr " $(readlink -f /etc/fstab; printf .)" : ".*" - 3
10
```

The space before command substitution prevent command from being crashed with string start with `-`, so we need to subtract 3.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that your third example works even without the `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8`, which significantly simplifies things if the encoding of the string will not be known in advance.

Comment: `expr length $(echo "*")` — nope. At least use double quotes: `expr length "$(…)"`. But this strips off trailing newlines from the command, it's an unescapable feature of command substitution. (You can work around it, but then the answer becomes even more complex.)

Answer (score 6):

Not sure how to do this with shell builtins ([Gnouc is though](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/160499/22222))  but the standard tools can help:

1. You can use `wc -m` which counts characters. Unfortunately, it also counts the final newline so you'd have to get rid of that first:

   ```
   readlink -f /etc/fstab | tr -d '\n' | wc -m
   ```
2. You can of course use `awk`

   ```
   readlink -f /etc/fstab | awk '{print length($0)}'
   ```
3. Or Perl

   ```
   readlink -f /etc/fstab | perl -lne 'print length'
   ```

Comment: Do you mean `expr` is a built-in? In which shell?

Answer (score 5):

I usually do it like this:

```
$ echo -n "$variable" | wc -m
10
```

To do commands I'd adapt it like so:

```
$ echo -n "$(readlink -f /etc/fstab)" | wc -m
10
```

This approach is similar to what you were doing in your 2 steps, except we're combining them into a single one liner.

Comment: You must use `-m` instead of `-c`. With unicode characters, your approach will be broken.

Comment: Why not simply `readlink -f /etc/fstab | wc -m` ?

Comment: Why do you use this unreliable method instead of `${#variable}`? At least use double quotes `echo -n "$variable"`, but this still fails if e.g. the value of `variable` is `-e`. When you use it in combination with a command substitution, keep in mind that trailing newlines are stripped off.

Comment: @philfrost b/c what I showed built off of what the op was already thinking. Also it works for any cmds that he may have setup prior in vars and wants their lengths afterwords. Also terdon has that example already.

Answer (score 1):

You can call external utilities (see other answers), but they will make your script slower, and it's hard to get the plumbing right.

#### Zsh

In zsh, you can write `${#$(readlink -f /etc/fstab)}` to get the length of the command substitution. Note that this isn't the length of the command output, it's the length of the output without any trailing newline.

If you want the exact length of the output, output an extra non-newline character at the end, and subtract one.

```
$((${#$(readlink -f /etc/fstab; echo .)} - 1))
```

If what you want is the payload in the command's output, then you need to subtract *two* here, because the output of `readlink -f` is the canonical path plus a newline.

```
$((${#$(readlink -f /etc/fstab; echo .)} - 2))
```

This differs from `${#$(readlink -f /etc/fstab)}` in the rare but possible case where the canonical path itself ends in a newline.

For this specific example, you don't need an external utility at all, because zsh has a built-in construct that's equivalent to `readlink -f`, through the history modifier `A`.

```
echo /etc/fstab(:A)
```

To get the length, use the history modifier in a parameter expansion:

```
${#${:-/etc/fstab}:A}
```

If you have the file name in a variable `filename`, that would be `${#filename:A}`.

#### Bourne/POSIX-style shells

None of the pure Bourne/POSIX shells (Bourne, ash, mksh, ksh93, bash, yash …) have any similar extension that I know of. If you need to apply a parameter substitution to the output of a command substitution or to nest parameter substitutions, use successive stages.

You can stuff the processing into a function if you like.

```
command_output_length_sans_trailing_newlines () {
  set -- "$("$@")"
  echo "${#1}"
}
```

or

```
command_output_length () {
  set -- "$("$@"; echo .)"
  echo "$((${#1} - 1))"
}
```

but there's usually no benefit; except with ksh93, that causes an extra fork to be able to use the output of the function, so it makes your script slower, and 
there's rarely any readability benefit.

Once again, the output of `readlink -f` is the canonical path plus a newline; if you want the length of the canonical path, subtract 2 instead of 1 in `command_output_length`. Using `command_output_length_sans_trailing_newlines` gives the right result only when the canonical path itself doesn't end in a newline.

#### Bytes vs characters

`${#…}` is supposed to be the length in characters, not in bytes, which makes a difference in multibyte locales. Reasonably up-to-date versions of ksh93, bash and zsh calculate the length in characters according to the value of `LC_CTYPE` at the time the `${#…}` construct is expanded. Many other common shells don't really support multibyte locales: as of dash 0.5.7, mksh 46 and posh 0.12.3, `${#…}` returns the length in bytes. If you want the length in characters in a reliable way, use the `wc` utility:

```
$(readlink -f /etc/fstab | wc -m)
```

As long as `$LC_CTYPE` designates a valid locale, you can be confident that this will either error out (on an ancient or restricted platform that doesn't support multibyte locales) or return the correct length in characters. (For Unicode, “length in characters” means the number of code points — number of glyphs is yet another story, due to complications such as combining characters.)

If you want the length in bytes, set `LC_CTYPE=C` temporarily, or use `wc -c` instead of `wc -m`.

Counting bytes or characters with `wc` includes any trailing newlines from the command. If you want the length of the canonical path in bytes, it's

```
$(($(readlink -f /etc/fstab | wc -c) - 1))
```

To get it in characters, subtract 2.

Comment: @cuonglm No, you need to subtract 1. `echo .` adds two characters, but the second character is a trailing newline which is stripped by the command substitution.

Comment: The newline is from `readlink` output, plus the `.` by `echo`. We both agree that `echo .` add two characters but the trailing newline was stripped. Try with `printf .` or see my answer http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/160499/38906.

Comment: @cuonglm The question asked the number of characters in the command's output. The output of `readlink` is the link target plus a newline.

Answer (score 0):

This works in `dash` but it does require that the targeted var is definitely empty or unset. That is why this is actually *two* commands - I explicitly empty `$l` in the first:

```
l=;printf '%.slen is %d and result is %s\n' \
    "${l:=$(readlink -f /etc/fstab)}" "${#l}" "$l"
```

#### OUTPUT

```
len is 10 and result is /etc/fstab
```

That's all shell builtins - not including the `readlink` of course - but evaluating it in the current shell that way implies that you must do the assignment before getting the len, which is why I `%.s`ilence the first argument in the `printf` format string and just add it again for the literal value at the tail of `printf`'s arg list.

With `eval`:

```
l=$(readlink -f /etc/fstab) eval 'l=${#l}:$l'
printf %s\\n "$l"
```

#### OUTPUT

```
10:/etc/fstab
```

You can get close to that same thing, but instead of the output in a variable in the first command you get it on stdout:

```
PS4='${#0}:$0' dash -cx '2>&1' "$(readlink -f /etc/fstab)"
```

...which writes...

```
10:/etc/fstab
```

...to file descriptor 1 without assigning any value to any vars in the current shell.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what the OP wanted to avoid? "I understand it is possible to do this by first saving the output to a variable: `variable=$(readlink -f /etc/fstab); echo ${#variable};` But I would like to remove the extra step."

Comment: @terdon, probably I misunderstood, but it was my impression that the semicolon was the problem and not the variable. That's why these get the len and output in a single simple command using only shell builtins. The shell doesn't exec readlink *then* exec `expr`, for instance. It probably *only* matters if somehow getting the len occludes the value, which I admit I'm having difficulty understanding why that may be, but I suspect there could be a case in which it mattered.

Comment: The `eval` way, by the way, is probably the cleanest here - it assigns the output and the len to the same var name in a single execution - *very* close to doing `l=length(l):out(l)`. Doing `expr length $(command)` *does* occlude the value in favor of the len, by the way.